# How can I resolve RouteNotFoundException?

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-blade

I'm trying to develope a program with Laravel, I have a problem with a Route, it shows me that is not define but it's already defined, also, I'm using Ajax.

This is the Error

[image]

This is my Ajax with URL and Route
[image]
And I tried to put the Route in that part of the code, but when I put there I get other problem.

I have tried this

[image]
Thank so much for your help.

Comment: Hello, please post the code instead of image. please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: 1- you should copy and paste your code here not attaching the images. 
2- If you want to send any picture of an error or specific things, you should use a screenshot, not your mobile.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

After adding new route you need to clear cache. So run this commands:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:cache
```

And check again

Answer (score 0):

You have same controller method two time define and you did changed only route name? so it can return error. remove first route then it will work fine.

```
Route::post('schedule/destory', 'Client\SchedulesController@destory')->name('client.schedules.destory');
Route::post('schedule/destory', 'Client\SchedulesController@destory')->name('orders.schedules.store');
```

please remove `Route::post('schedule/destory', 'Client\SchedulesController@destory')->name('client.schedules.destory');` route.